# How to return default display style of element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

Different HTML elements have different default `display` value. For example:

- `div` is `block`
- `span` is `inline-block`

I have element which is hidden with javascript:

```
element.style.display = 'none';
```

How can I set the correct default value back, without having to deduce it from the element type:

```
// Sets 'block' if 'element' is 'div', 'inline-block' if 'span', etc.    
element.style.display = ?;
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) doesn't seem to list `default` or anything similar for this.

No jQuery or similar libraries, vanilla Javascript only.

Comment: Try `element.style.display = null` this should remove the inline style for `display`

Comment: Try inherit, maybe works

Comment: Use element.style.display = 'initial'; it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Remove Property.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.removeProperty( 'display' );
```

This will then use the default.